# how to avoid "/*" being substitute to files/dirs in the root directory in a bash script?

Tags: bash

In a bash script, when an input line contains the starting comment token /* it is evaluated to all entries in root directory "/". How can we avoid this?

Edit: Code from comment in more readable form:

```
while read line; do
    echo -e "input line: [$line]"
    aaa=`echo -e $line`
    echo -e "aaa=$aaa"
done < $infile
```

Comment: In a bash script, the starting comment token is '#', not '/*'.

Comment: post the snippit of code in question

Comment: while read line; do
    echo -e "input line: [$line]"
    aaa=`echo -e $line`
    echo -e "aaa=$aaa"
done < $infile

Comment: sorry not familiar with the input system.
when input contains "/*" i got a list of the entries in root dir in the output of  echo -e "aaa=$aaa"

Answer (score 2):

You can tell bash to ignore certain patterns when doing file expansion:

```
$ export GLOBIGNORE='/*'
$ ls /* | wc
ls: cannot access /*: No such file or directory
      0       0       0
```

or you can disable pathname expansion altogether using the set builtin: `set -f`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a variable without putting it in double-quotes, its value is parsed in a couple of ways after being substituted: it's broken into "words", and wildcards get expanded.  In your case, the line:

```
aaa=`echo -e $line`
```

is causing trouble because there are no quotes around `$line` -- it'll expand wildcards, convert strings of spaces, tabs, etc into single spaces, and maybe some other things I haven't though of.  BTW, `read line` will trim leading and trailing whitespace, and join lines ending with a backslash; if you don't want this, use `IFS= read -r line` instead.  Finally, using `echo -e` twice will lead to double-interpretation of escape sequences in the input file.  Here's my recommended rewrite:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo -e "input line: [$line]"
    aaa=$(echo -e "$line")
    echo "aaa=$aaa"
done < "$infile"
```